# Boolean Algebra simplify minterms

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have this equation

$$\bar{A}\cdot\bar{B}\cdot\bar{C} + A\cdot\bar{B}\cdot C + A\cdot B\cdot \bar{C} + A \cdot B\cdot C$$

and need to simplify it. I have got as far as I can and spent a good 2 hours at it. I've realized I now need to use *De Morgan's law* to continue however I am baffled as to which rule to use. If someone could send me in the right direction that would be great!

$$\bar{A}\cdot\bar{B}\cdot\bar{C} + A\cdot\bar{B}\cdot C + A\cdot B\cdot \bar{C} + A \cdot B\cdot C$$

$$\bar{A}\cdot\bar{B}\cdot\bar{C} + A(\bar{B}\cdot\bar{C} + B\cdot\bar{C} + B\cdot C$$

$$\bar{A}\cdot\bar{B}\cdot\bar{C} + A(\bar{B}\cdot C + B(\bar{C} + C)) $$

$$\bar{A}\cdot\bar{B}\cdot\bar{C} + A(\bar{B}\cdot C + B) $$

$$\bar{A}\cdot\bar{B}\cdot\bar{C} + A(C + B) $$

Thanks

Comment: I have edited the first part of your equation to use $\LaTeX$ formatting.  Could you try to edit the rest of your question to do so as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picking up where you (initially) left off (your work thus far is correct, save for the last line were you remove $\overline B$)...

$$\begin{align} &\overline{A}\cdot\overline{B}\cdot\overline{C} + A\cdot\overline{B}\cdot C + A\cdot B\cdot \overline{C} + A \cdot B\cdot C \\ \\
&\vdots \\ \\
&=\overline A \cdot \overline B \cdot \overline C + A(\overline B\cdot C+B) \\ \\
& = \overline A \cdot \overline B \cdot \overline C + A\cdot \overline B \cdot C + AB\tag{as good as it gets!}\\ \\ 
& = \overline B(\overline A \cdot \overline C + A\cdot C) + AB\tag{doesn't help any}\\ \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Updated accordingly...

Comment: How do you go from $$\bar{A}\cdot\bar{B}\cdot\bar{C} + A(\bar{B}\cdot C + B) $$ Why is there a bar above B and C in your next line of working?

Comment: I was in the process of updating after the "not" symbols were clarified: got to the line you referred to first, but not yet to the ensuing line.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: You're welcome, @user2437672

Answer (score 1):

The $\mathrm{ExOR}$ function can be denoted by: $\oplus$ ; $X \oplus Y=\overline {X}\cdot Y +X \cdot \overline{Y} $.

Also $\overline{X \oplus Y}=\overline {X}\cdot \overline{Y} +X \cdot {Y} $

Hence $$\begin{align}
\bar{A}\cdot\bar{B}\cdot\bar{C} + A\cdot\bar{B}\cdot C + A\cdot B\cdot \bar{C} + A \cdot B\cdot C &=\left(\bar{A}\cdot\bar{B}\cdot\bar{C} + A\cdot\bar{B}\cdot C \right)+ \left(A\cdot B\cdot \bar{C} + A \cdot B\cdot C \right) \\
&=\bar{B}\left(\bar{A}\cdot\bar{C} + A\cdot C \right)+A\cdot B\left(\bar{C} + C \right)\\
&=\bar{B}\left(\overline{A \oplus C}\right)+A\cdot B\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: I use the negated ExOR function since if implemented using logic gates, the function will require lesser number of components than the other answers.

Comment: This is brilliant. I completely didn't even think of using an ExOR. This helps me with my extended part as well. Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

If you use a karnaugh map:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
C, AB  & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ \hline
0 & 1  &   & 1 &  \\ \hline
1 &    &   & 1 & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}
\equiv
\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C} + A\bar{B} C + AB\bar{C} + ABC
$$

Which suggests Xor of the 2 groups:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
C, AB  & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ \hline
0 &    &   & 1 & 1\\ \hline
1 &    &   & 1 & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}
\equiv A
$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
C, AB  & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ \hline
0 & 1  &   &   & 1\\ \hline
1 &    &   &   &  \\ \hline
\end{array}
\equiv \overline B \cdot \overline C
$$

Which gives:
$$A \oplus (\overline B \cdot \overline C)$$

Comment: The leftmost columns of all the 3 maps cannot be $0$ on both rows!

Comment: Thank you for catching that typo.  I'm still a bit fresh with Latex ^_^

Comment: Doesn't the second k-map  have a rogue $1$ at $A\cdot \bar{B}\cdot \bar{C}$???

Comment: Yes it does, both the 2nd and 3rd do.  Xor only keeps parity, so if you added the 2nd and 3rd kmap $\pmod 2$ you get the first one.  It's my sneaky trick to use xor with kmaps.

Comment: But $A \oplus (\overline B \cdot \overline C)$=$A \overline{(\overline B \cdot \overline C)}+\bar{A} (\overline B \cdot \overline C)$=$A ( B +  C)+\bar{A} (\overline B \cdot \overline C)$=$AB +  AC+\bar{A}\bar{B} + \bar{A} \bar{C} \ne\bar{A}\cdot\bar{B}\cdot\bar{C} + A\cdot\bar{B}\cdot C + A\cdot B\cdot \bar{C} + A \cdot B\cdot C$

Comment: Hehe. I think your last step you accidentally distributed $\bar{A}(\bar{B}\cdot\bar{C})$ rather than just removing the paren.  If you want to check them algebraically, don't forget that $X \equiv XY + X\bar{Y}$.  Or you can check the 8 input combinations.

Comment: aaahh.. yes, my bad.$A ( B +  C)+\bar{A} (\overline B \cdot \overline C)= AB +  AC+\bar{A}\bar{B} + \bar{A}\bar{B} \bar{C} $

Answer (score 0):

$\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C} + A\bar{B}C + AB\bar{C} + ABC $
$= \bar{A}\bar{B}C + A\bar{B}C + AB(\bar{C} + C) $
$= \bar{A}\bar{B}C + A\bar{B}C + AB $
$= C(\bar{A}\bar{B} + A\bar{B}) + AB $
$= C(\bar{B}(\bar{A} + A)) + AB $
$= C\bar{B} + AB$

$\bar{A} = \text{not}\space A$

Comment: Your first equation shifts from $A'B'C'$ to $A'B'C$: you forgot to negate the C in the first disjunct.