# Can this Boolean expression be simplified any further?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have simplified a Boolean expression to
$$(\lnot a \land \lnot b \land \lnot c) \lor (a \land (b \lor c)).$$
Is there any way to simplify this further, e.g. using De Morgan's or anything?

Comment: What do you mean by $a(b\land c)$? Do you really want $(a\land b\land c)$ here?

Comment: Sorry, I put an "and" sign instead of an "or" sign, I've corrected it.

Comment: @J0FVB, you still seem to use two different notations in one expression. Should there be a symbol between $a$ and $b\lor c$?

Comment: It’s still not clear; are you using juxtaposition as well as $\land$ to mean **and**? I.e., is this $$(\neg a\land\neg b\land\neg c)\lor\big(c\land(b\lor c)\big)\;?$$

Comment: you mean `a` not `c` right?

Comment: @Cruncher: Yes, that was a typo. $$(\neg a\land\neg b\land\neg c)\lor\big(a\land(b\lor c)\big)$$

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Yes, you are correct, I've edited the question.

Comment: I don't think this can really be simplified at all. Perhaps the best you can do is change the first part to: $ \neg(a\lor b\lor c) $

Comment: Okay - that means I'm done (or almost done) with my simplification. Thanks.

Comment: You can manipulate it into other forms that might be simpler for specific purposes. For instance, $$(\neg a\land\neg b\land\neg c)\lor(a\land b)\lor(a\land c)\;,$$ the disjunctive normal form, might in some contexts be considered a simplification. If you have exclusive or available, which I’ll write $\oplus$, you can reduce it to $$\neg\big(a\oplus(b\lor c)\big)\;,$$ which some might consider a simplification.

Comment: Yes - this is what I was looking for, I think. Thanks.

Comment: I'd add lastly that in circuitry these are often simplified down to using all $ \lor $ or all $ \land $ as it's cheaper to mass produce a tonne of the same logic gates. Also @BrianM.Scott I wouldn't have particularly considered xor as it's really just a shortcut for $ a\land \neg b \lor \neg a \land b $. But my heart is generally in a computer science context, where you have to implement xor in circuitry anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression can no further be simplified, using only $\land,\lor, \;\text{and/or}\;\lnot$. So how you choose to present the expression depends on context and/or your preference. If you want to minimize the repetition of variables, your posted expression does so.

However, we *can* put the expression into one of a number of standard forms, ***disjunctive normal form***, by merely expanding the second term, using the distributivity of conjunction over disjunction, to get:

$$(\lnot a \land \lnot b \land \lnot c) \lor (a \land (b\lor c))\equiv (\lnot a \land \lnot b \land \lnot c)\lor (a\land b) \lor (a \land c)$$

We could also reconfigurate your original post to present it in ***conjunctive normal form:*** $$(\lnot a \land \lnot b \land \lnot c) \lor (a \land (b\lor c))\equiv (\lnot a \lor b \lor c) \land (a \lor \lnot b) \land (a \lor \lnot c)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since at the time I'm posting this, there may be a typo in the question, I'm taking the expression to be simplified to be $ (\neg a\land\neg b\land\neg c)\lor\big(a\land(b\lor c)\big) $.

Doing the prior simplification:$(\neg a\land\neg b\land\neg c)\lor\big(a\land(b\lor c)\big)=(\neg a\land\neg b\land\neg c)\lor\big((a\land b)\lor (a \land c)\big)$ and then using a karnaugh map:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
a, bc  & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ \hline
0 & 1  &   &  &  \\ \hline
1 &    & 1  & 1 & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}=a \oplus (\neg b \land \neg c)
$$

Comment: Using the *actual* k-map for this question gives you `1000` for top row, and `0111` for bottom row, which then evaluates to exactly the op's expression

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly, thanks to BrianM.Scott and Cruncher. An example of the exor(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) trick is http://math.stackexchange.com/a/578670/59553

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to rewrite this, if you're allowed to use something other than $\;\land,\lor,\lnot\;$, is the following:
\begin{align}
& (\lnot a \land \lnot b \land \lnot c) \;\lor\; \big(a \land(b \lor c)\big) \\
= & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"DeMorgan -- to make the left and right parts similar"} \\
& \big(\lnot a\land \lnot (b \lor c)\big) \;\lor\; \big(a \land(b \lor c)\big) \\
= & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"$\;(p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)\;$ is one of the ways to write $\;p \equiv q\;$"} \\
& a \;\equiv\; b \lor c \\
\end{align}